# Is it possible to pass multiple variables to a function that are not declared locally in the previous function that calls it (or globally declared)?

Tags: python, function, selenium

In python/Selenium I have a web automation script that uses 5 seperate functions to complete a task. The function call chain is linear as each one relies on the last to have executed.

The problem I am having is that I do not want to declare all the variables to use in the final function 'checkout' globally.
I cannot take input for the  variables in any of the functions as it would delay the functions which are time critical.

I can however take these before the timer has finished and the program begins. The variables are all currently local to the main function that does this. In doing this I would have to pass all 10 variables through every function until the final one. 
Is there a way to avoid this and just 'pass' the variables to the final function despite them not being global or locally declared in the previous function?

Comment: Would you be able to explain with code in your post? I think it would make more sense that way

Comment: Take a look at [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Define a class that contains 10 properties, one for each of the variables that you want to pass. Now you create an instance of that class and put the values into the properties. Now you can just pass the class instance around to each method and unpack the values inside the method and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have all the functions as methods in a class that holds these variables as a state like:

```
class MyRunner():

    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3

    def method1(self):
        print("Call of method 1", self.val1, self.val2, self.val3)

    def method2(self):
        print("Call of method 2", self.val1, self.val2, self.val3)

    def method3(self):
        print("Call of method 3", self.val1, self.val2, self.val3)


runner = MyRunner(10, 20, 30)
runner.method1()
runner.method2()
runner.method3()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! An effective solution there that I didn’t even think about. Credit to you for that!